# Show upvotes and downvotes for questions outside of Stack Overflow

Tags: support

On Stack Overflow, I've noticed that clicking on a question's score will display the total number of upvotes for that question, as well as the total number of downvotes. However, I've noticed that clicking on a question's score on other Stack Exchange sites doesn't display the total number of upvotes and downvotes. Is there any other way to display the total number of upvotes and downvotes for Stack Exchange sites outside of Stack Overflow?

Comment: I've always wondered why this feature appears to exist on Stack Overflow, but not on any of the other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: U NEED MOAR POINTS!!!

Comment: @Mysticial Does that mean that the feature exists on all sites, but requires a certain amount of reputation on each site?

Comment: Anyways, it's a 1k privilege. Which you have on SO, but not anywhere else.

Comment: You need to have at least 1,000 reputation on the site in order to gain that ability.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user

Comment: I wish I hadn't asked such an obvious question. I feel like a worthless and reprehensible person now. :( (BTW, I didn't realize that the answer to this question was supposed to be obvious until it got 9 downvotes - that really shows how much the community hates me, doesn't it?)

Comment: Downvotes don't have anything to do with you as a person, and they certainly have never implied hatred. They just speak on the quality and/or usefulness of the question itself. If you're really wondering why the question was downvoted, check out the tooltip on the down arrow: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"

Comment: @AndersonGreen "downvote the question, not the person". Don't take it personally, [_especially_ on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: It still helped me out, I did not find https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user when searching meta for "show upvotes and downvotes", in the end I used my search engine and then found this here. Upvote in my case, perhaps even according to meta rules.

Answer (score 8):

You need [1000 rep to see vote splits](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) (750 on beta sites).

If you're only seeing vote splits on Stack Overflow, then you must have >1000 rep on SO and <1000 on the other sites. Privileges are determined on each site by your reputation on only that site, so you will need to earn 1000 rep on any site you want to see vote splits for.

Comment: Why is it <1000 on the other sites instead of >1000?

Comment: @AndersonGreen I meant that in order for you to not see the vote split, it must be true that you have <1000 on the other sites. The requirement is the same on all sites.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: It's 1,000 reputation on all normal sites, and 750 reputation on beta sites (lower activity). I believe it's lower on private betas, but those only last about a week.

Comment: Also, why did my question get so many downvotes? Does it demonstrate some kind of extreme ignorance on my part? I didn't realize that the answer to this question was supposed to be obvious.

Comment: @AndersonGreen I don't know for sure, since I didn't vote on it. Did you mean to leave the comment on the original question? People probably think it's obvious (which it is _if_ you've been around long enough, _but_ we were all new at one point!), but I think it's a reasonable question. People are probably downvoting because similar questions (e.g. "why aren't my privileges the same on all sites?") have been asked many times before.